# How do I server AJAX calls using JSON with Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-ajax

I know MVC controllers are quite good at serving JSON formatted AJAX requests, but is there any built-in ASP.NET functionality I can use for these type calls from a plain old web forms site?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use built-in ASP.NET AJAX.

Option 1 - use a web service (if you want the functionality to be reusable):

- create a web service (.asmx) with [ScriptService] attribute,
- add a  to your page and add the web service to its Services collection,
- use JavaScript proxy generated by ScriptManager in yor page.

Option 2 - use page methods (if you want the functionality on a single page without creating a web service):

- define static methods in your page, add [WebMethod] attribute to them,
- add a ScriptManager with EnablePageMethods="true",
- use PageMethods object to call these method from JavaScript.

In either case JSON will be used for data transfer.

Here is an extensive [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg%29%29/learn/Ajax/tutorial-05-cs.aspx) with some code samples.

However, ASP.NET AJAX is often blamed for inefficiency - for instance, JS it generates tends to be rather large. So, if you are concerned with performance, you'd want to test it thoroughly.

You might also have a look at this thread: [.NET AJAX Calls to ASMX or ASPX or ASHX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673075/net-ajax-calls-to-asmx-or-aspx-or-ashx)

Comment: Page methods was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use **generic web handler**. i.e. **ashx**. These are even faster than *MVC* actions.

Answer (score 2):

Web API works fine with Web Forms. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

Comment: In theory it can. However, in practical use, you may meet the issue of locking-session: every request from web-form page is associated with the user session by default, so you can only do ajax requests one-by-one. It may or may not be important for your project

Comment: You can use read-only session for most requests and read-write for login/logout. It prevents the lock issue. Session is not enabled for Web API by default. I have to call the method from Application_PostAuthorizeRequest: HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);

Comment: I'm concerned, because that we tried to include a Web API module in a legacy ASP.NET web form. It's true that Web API doesn't have session by default, but when it is coupled with Web Form, it does. We can even read the session info from the API request. In common case it is not a problem, until we have some heavy API call

Comment: I think I tried the Read Only approach one time before, but it's hard because the mix among web forms and web api. Maybe I'd give it a retry

Answer (score 0):

If you've got .NET 3.5 installed on the server, you can take advantage of the [JSON serialization tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx) that ship with the framework.

This uses the [DataContractJsonserializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method in this scenario is using a generic web handler (.ashx) and JSON.net http://james.newtonking.com/json

It's simple, fast and lightweight.

A simple example would be:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
        string jsonOutput = string.Empty;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        using (var db = new MyDBContext())
        {
            var dbResult = db.myobject.select();
            jsonOutput = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbResult);
        }
        context.Response.Write(jsonOutput); 
}
```