# jQuery Calling an ASMX Web Service that Returns Data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using jsTree to organize pages created by users. Upon right-clicking and pressing "Rename" I want to fire a JS function that hits a function in my code behind without post back (if possible). I want it to grab whichever item's I'm on ID and rename it in the database and update the jsTree.

Here is a sample code-behind function:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
protected void RenamePage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Global.conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("contentPageUpdate", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Global.SafeSqlLiteral(txtPage.Text, 1);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();

        //Update Content Page Repeater
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("contentPageGetAll", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, so - what have you tried so far? what specific problems have you faced?

Comment: I have never worked with jQuery hitting c# functions before. Not sure exactly where to start. Need a jumping off point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of it as jQuery hitting C# functions, but rather jQuery hitting a resource identified by a URI.

When you make an AJAX request with jQuery, you give the url of the destination and it does a standard HttpRequest for that url.  This can be a page (webforms) or a controller action (MVC).

Since it looks like you're using webforms, you could make a new page to handle this request.  If you put a breakpoint in the `Page_Load` method you'll see that it gets fired when you invoke the AJAX method:

In the javascript for the right click you can use jQuery's `ajax` method like so:

```
$.ajax('mypage.aspx');
```

In your mypage.aspx:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("You called me!");
}
```

You can get the response that is written back by adding a few arguments to your `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax('mypage.aspx', { success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert(data);
}});
```

Comment: This is close I think. I currently have Pages.aspx with the jsTree. I want it to hit a function in Pages.aspx.cs, Is that possible?

Comment: If that method is exposed by a Url then sure, otherwise no.  We used to create aspx files in an 'ajax' folder that didn't have any markup, and just returned the required response from Page_Load.  These fragments could be hit up by ajax as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly what you're trying to do, but I think this *might* give you a basic idea of what's involved as far as making calls to URIs with JQuery and doing something 'databasey'*  ;-)

You'll need @MichaelShimmins' Jquery AJax code too (I ommitted it from my post)

[Autocomplete jquery and SQL , ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084637/autocomplete-jquery-and-sql-asp-net/5085399#5085399)

HTH.

`* (that's not a technical term - apologies)`