# "WebMethod" attribute in the aspx and asmx files, difference?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I noticed in some code that [**WebMethod**] attribute is used in the code-behind file of an **aspx** page.

But as I remember it, this attribute is used to expose Web Service and it is often seen in **asmx** file.

So what's the difference between these 2 usages?

Thanks.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673075/net-ajax-calls-to-asmx-or-aspx-or-ashx

Comment: Thanks, I am reading that thread. It's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If that method is also static, you can call that method via javascript/ajax, without a full page postback.
Note that your `ScriptManager` needs to have the `EnablePageMethods` property set to true.

Comment: Yes, the method I saw with this attribute is static. Is that some kind of Ajax? BTW, what if it is not static?

Comment: Yes, it can be used via javascript, for example http://ajaxtoolkit.net/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx uses that idea...

Answer (score 1):

Webmethods in code behind are used for AJAX calls. If you are using jquery or similar and you need to implement an ajax functionality on your page then you will have to define you method with WebMethod attribute and have to make it public static. Then only it will work.

WebMethod's concept I feel has been taken from web services. Since asp.net didn't have any defined way of handling ajax requests to method of page behind, they have extended this feature to be used for code behind methods.

Keep a watch that being public static methods you may not be able to use your page class' internal properties here. so, you will need to deal with that.

Comment: If we really want AJAX, why not just write some asmx Web Service or use WCF and let Javascript to call that? Why do we have to include the crippled static methods in our page class?

Comment: There can be multiple reasons. 1) The functionality is very small that you dont wanna have a service call. Because when you expose a service call you have to add a new web method / operation contract. 2) The service call is expensive and will take more time to return (assuming we have to same logic) because of the layers involved in service communications. Also a code behind web method resides in the same app pool there for the call is really quick. - Thats what I feel. Others may have different opinion.