# Is it possible to use aspx.cs file as a server end controller?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I am fairly new to web forms. I am using custom file upload component. I would like to upload file in a specific folder of my local machine and I have written code in the `Default.aspx.cs` file instead of `Default.ahsx` page. The file which I upload is uploaded successfully(UI level only) and I'm getting  wondered, I cannot able to get the file in code behind (i.e., in aspx.cs file). Breakpoints also not hit. In the Network tab of browser, status code is returned as 200.

Here is what I've tried.

**My aspx.cs file**

```
 public static object Save(HttpContext context)

    {
     // Debugger is not hitting 

        <Code to save file>
        return "";

    }
```

**Aspx file**

```
<div id="app">
        <custom-uploader :async-settings="path"></custom-uploader>
    </div>
    <script>

        Vue.use(customUploader.UploaderPlugin);
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: function () {
                return {
                    path: {
                        saveUrl: 'Default.aspx/Save',
                        removeUrl: 'https://aspnetmvc.syncfusion.com/services/api/uploadbox/Remove'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the javascript console of your browser?

Comment: There are several articles on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673075/net-ajax-calls-to-asmx-or-aspx-or-ashx https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript

Comment: I don't get any error in console. The thing I found was GET is 200 OK whereas POST is 301 Moved Permanently.

Comment: Anyone please help to resolve this.